# Unable to see messages using django register

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-registration, django-messages

I have an app with views.py as follows

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.
def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']

        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        email = request.POST['email']

        if password1==password2:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request,'username taken')

                return redirect('register')
            elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request,'email taken')

                return redirect('register')
            else:
                user= User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password1, email=email, first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name)
                user.save();

                print('user created')
        else:
            print('password missmatch')
            return redirect('register')
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request,'register.html')
```

I have added a for loop for showing the messages in register.html

```
    
{% for message in messages %}
      <h3> {{message}} </h3>
{% endfor %}
```

I can't able to see messages when the for loop is available but i can see message address when for loop is removed. Can some explain and help me how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

This might be your issue, reading the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/) for the messages framework it says `If you’re using the context processor, your template should be rendered with a RequestContext. Otherwise, ensure messages is available to the template context.`

In your example, it would be something like this

```
from django.template import RequestContext
...
render(RequestContext(request), 'register.html')
```

Comment: I tried to replicate the same as you have mentioned, but it didnt work and raising some more errors. Can you please check once again?

Comment: It was just a guess, it's the best I can do with the code you provided. See if you can create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)